# How do I add an additional field to the ckeditor_assets table when using the ckeditor rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

According to the [README for the CKEditor gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#default-scope), I should be able to set an alternative scope for images and attachments. I tried to do this and it simply translates this to a field in the ckeditor_assets table.

I can create a migration to add the required field but how do I configure ckeditor (presumably via the autogenerated models) so that the field is populated with the right data when a new record is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

I used a before_save filter to set the field as I wanted it. Then the methods are altered in application controller to use the field as a scope.

```
# models/ckeditor/asset.rb

before_save :set_company_id

def set_company_id
  self.company_id = assetable.try(:company_id)
end


# controllers/application_controller.rb

protected

def ckeditor_pictures_scope(options = { :company_id => "#{company_id}" })
  ckeditor_filebrowser_scope(options)
end

def ckeditor_attachment_files_scope(options = { :company_id => "#{company_id}" })
  ckeditor_filebrowser_scope(options)
end
```

Comment: This no longer works as the super controller of `Ckeditor::ApplicationController` was changed from `ApplicationController` to `ActionController::Base` (release 4.1.0 of ckeditor gem). As a work-around I changed the gem to inherit from `ApplicationController` as this would also provide the proper auth/auth, in addition to scoping.

Comment: This now longer work in ckeditor gem since version 4.2.4 as this assetable process has been removed. For now, I use the fork indicated here: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/pull/778 that revert this change

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the simplest solution:

```
#controllers/application_controller.rb
protected

def ckeditor_pictures_scope(options = { :assetable_id => "#{current_page.id}" ,:assetable_type => "Page" })
  ckeditor_filebrowser_scope(options)
end

def ckeditor_attachment_files_scope(options = { :assetable_id => "#{current_page.id}" ,:assetable_type => "Page" })
  ckeditor_filebrowser_scope(options)
end


def ckeditor_before_create_asset(asset)
  asset.assetable = current_page if current_page
  return true
end
```